# Boolean operations for 3D objects

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, computational-geometry

I want to get a 3D object by Boolean operation, but I cannot find the information that I need to do this. How do I get something like the animation below?

[image]

This is my code:

```
(*Corpo Principal*)
orig = {0, 0, 0};
diam1 = 50;
r1 = diam1/2;
comp = 200;

(*Furo*)
diam2 = 15;
r2 = diam2/2;

(*Rasgo*)
altRasgo = 30;
largRasgo = 15;

Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{orig, {comp, 0, 0}}, r1],Cylinder[{{altRasgo/2, 0, -r1}, {altRasgo/2, 0, r1}}, r2],Cuboid[{0, -r1, -7.5}, {30, r1, 7.5}]}]
```

> [image]

Comment: animation is not shown

Comment: yeah... it's being blocked by my firewall

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's split the components:

```
reg = {Cylinder[{orig, {comp, 0, 0}}, r1], 
Cylinder[{{altRasgo/2, 0, -r1}, {altRasgo/2, 0, r1}}, r2], 
Cuboid[{0, -r1, -7.5}, {30, r1, 7.5}]};
```

and use `RegionDifference` twice:

```
rr = RegionDifference[RegionDifference[reg[[1]], reg[[2]]], reg[[3]]];
```

Then you can

```
RegionPlot3D[rr, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Directly with regions:

```
comp = 200;
altRasgo = 30;
r1 = 25;
r2 = 7.5;

region1 = (comp > x > 0 && y^2 + z^2 < r1^2);
region2 = (((x - altRasgo/2)^2 + y^2) < r2^2 && r1 > z > -r1);
region3 = (0 < x < 30 && -r1 < y < r1 && -7.5 < z < 7.5);
RegionPlot3D[
 region1 && ! region2 && ! region3, {x, 0, comp}, {y, -comp/2, 
  comp/2}, {z, -comp/2, comp/2}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotStyle -> Darker[Gray]]
```

[image]

Generation higher quality model:

```
r = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   region, {x, y, z}], {{0, comp}, {-comp/2, comp/2}, {-comp/2, 
    comp/2}}, Method -> "RegionPlot3D", MaxCellMeasure -> 10];
rr = GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates@#, MeshCells[#, 2]] &@r;
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Darker[Gray], rr}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With the new in version 12.1 [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) you get very crisp corners:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*Corpo Principal*)
orig = {0, 0, 0};
diam1 = 50;
r1 = diam1/2;
comp = 200;

(*Furo*)
diam2 = 15;
r2 = diam2/2;

(*Rasgo*)
altRasgo = 30;
largRasgo = 15;
reg = {Cylinder[{orig, {comp, 0, 0}}, r1], 
  Cylinder[{{altRasgo/2, 0, -r1}, {altRasgo/2, 0, r1}}, r2], 
  Cuboid[{0, -r1, -7.5}, {30, r1, 7.5}]}; rr = 
 RegionDifference[RegionDifference[reg[[1]], reg[[2]]], reg[[3]]];
ocr = OpenCascadeShapeBooleanRegion[rr];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[ocr, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"LinearDeflection" -> 0.5}];

groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
```

[image]